# How to configure and build lzma on CentOS 6?

Tags: r, linux, centos, lzma, xz

I am trying to configure and build lzma version 5.0.3 or higher on CentOS 6. I try install R version 3.5.2.

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib
```

But this error

```
Checking if lzma version >= 5.0.3... no
```

I installed lzma version 4.999.

Comment: *"I installed lzma version 4.999"* - To state the obvious, you should install version 5.0.3 or newer. You should state where you are having trouble building lzma, not R.

Comment: BTW: You are not asking a programming question! Point is, you're trying to build and install some software, which is only remotely related to programming. Take this to e.g. superuser.com. Also, before applying suggested tags, please read their description!

Answer (score -1):

There is no 5.x.x version package available for CentOS 6 
They are having beta version at 4.9.9
[Click to check](https://pkgs.org/download/lzma)

I suggest you to upgrade your CentOS 6 to CentOS 7
And then you will get support in OS to install latest distribution of this and other packages

> sudo yum install xz

And also you can go to [this](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=liblzma.so.5%28%29%2864bit%29&submit=Search%20...&system=CentOS%206&arch=) link and download it manually and install it us

> sudo rpm -i {package}

Answer (score -1):

`R` 3.5.2 is [available](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/epel-x86_64/R-core-3.5.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) in EPEL repository.

Just install it from packages:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install R
```