# R version 4.0.0 on Centos 6

Tags: r, centos6, lzma, r-4.0.0

Installing R.4.0.0 on Centos 6 , I obtain the below error.

> Error lzma version >=5.0.3 ..no.

Is there a newer `lzma` version for Centos 6? R version 3.6 runs ok, I guess it uses `lzma 4.9`.

Comment: perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351312/how-to-configure-and-build-lzma-on-centos-6?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: CentOS 6 is *ancient*. We still use it in special cases at work because of special requirements, and it’s an incredible pain. I strongly recommend upgrading. Everything for CentOS 6 is outdated.